# form_for going to the wrong URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I'm on the order view page, and I want to update a line item on that order:

I have my route:

```
  resources :order_line_details do
    member do 
      put  :update_barcode
    end
  end
```

Then my form_for :

```
<%= form_for update_barcode_order_line_detail_path(@order_line_detail) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :hds_barcode  %>
<%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit though, it just goes to the order again:

```
No route matches "/orders/20888"
```

Rake routes:(for orders and orderlinedetails)

```
orders GET      /orders(.:format)                                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"orders"}
                                  orders POST     /orders(.:format)                                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"orders"}
                               new_order GET      /orders/new(.:format)                                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"orders"}
                              edit_order GET      /orders/:id/edit(.:format)                                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"orders"}
                                   order GET      /orders/:id(.:format)                                          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders"}
                                   order PUT      /orders/:id(.:format)                                          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"orders"}
                                   order DELETE   /orders/:id(.:format)                                          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"orders"}


   update_barcode_order_line_detail PUT      /order_line_details/:id/update_barcode(.:format)               {:action=>"update_barcode", :controller=>"order_line_details"}
                      order_line_details GET      /order_line_details(.:format)                                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"order_line_details"}
                      order_line_details POST     /order_line_details(.:format)                                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"order_line_details"}
                   new_order_line_detail GET      /order_line_details/new(.:format)                              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"order_line_details"}
                  edit_order_line_detail GET      /order_line_details/:id/edit(.:format)                         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"order_line_details"}
                       order_line_detail GET      /order_line_details/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"order_line_details"}
                       order_line_detail PUT      /order_line_details/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"order_line_details"}
                       order_line_detail DELETE   /order_line_details/:id(.:format)                              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"order_line_details"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post your `rake routes` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first argument to the `form_for` method should be the object that the form is for. Then you can manually change the default url with the :url parameter. Try doing it like this instead:

```
<%= form_for @order_line_detail, :url => update_barcode_order_line_detail_path(@order_line_detail) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :hds_barcode  %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Just out of curiousity, why do you need to specify the :url, when the url is in the route?  Isn't that a little redundant?  How is that different for doing form_for update_barcode_order_line_detail_path(@order_line_detail) ? Like you do in link_to?

Comment: The thing with form_for is that the url specification is not necessary as long as the routing matches the objects. But when you want to post to customized routes (such as a special member route) then you need to add the exact url. And the url_helper method needs the object again to generate the correct one. Hope I wasn't too unclear.

Comment: Ah, so if I just went to one of the rest routes I'd be fine.  Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I had a nested route and worked with 
<%= form_for :reservation, :url => create_reservation_path(@restaurant, @reservation) do |f| %>